# " I have never " or " I haven't "

Tags: grammar, difference

> (A) "I have never written a letter in English."
>   (B) "I haven't written a letter in English."
>   (C) "I haven't ever written a letter in English."

Do they have same meaning? Which one does sound natural?

Answer (score 4):

"I have never ..." and "I haven't ever ..." mean the same thing.

"I haven't ..." is not quite the same. Depending on the context, it COULD mean "never", or it could mean that you have not done this in this particular case.

For example, suppose you're boss assigned you to write three versions of a letter to be sent to clients: one in English, one in Spanish, and one in German. Some time later he asks if you've completed the job, and you say, "I haven't written a letter in English." In this context you don't mean that you've NEVER written a letter in English, just that you haven't written a letter in English on this particular subject.